# How to test a Google Guava Predicate factory kind of class

Tags: java, functional-programming, guava, predicate

I have a class called XxxPredicateFactory which return a single predicate or predicate combination. Something like this:

```
Public class XxxPredicateFactory {

     public Predicate<Abc> create() {
          if (this) {
              return new HelloPredicate<Abc>();
          }
          else if (that) {
              return new WorldPredicate<Abc>();
          }
          else {
               return Predicates.or(new HelloPredicate<Abc>(), new WorldPredicate<Abc>());
          }
     }

}
```

For the if and else if, it seems easy to test, but for the else part I am not quite sure how can I test this? How can I capture this situation?

Comment: Create a class that extends `XxxPredicateFactory` (since it's not final) and set the internal state of the instance so that both `this`and `that` are `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just test that the returned predicate returns `true` for both things that `HelloPredicate` should return `true` for and things that `WorldPredicate` should return `true` for?

Comment: Could you please add some code for testing the last statement? return Predicates.or(new HelloPredicate<Abc>(), new WorldPredicate<Abc>());